# Instagram account does not have a user ID associated with it

Tags: instagram-api

I'm doing work for my client with the following instagram account: http://instagram.com/fitxposed

**The problem is, I can't find any instagram user ID associated with that account.**

I've tried entering that user into here: http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id and it returns nothing.

I also tried this method:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]
```

And that also returned nothing.

I've tried both of the above methods with other instagram names including my own and they all work fine.

Does the fitxposed account have some sort of privacy settings enabled or something? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think so, check http://instagram.com/fitxposed/media (no access_token needed)... at the end of the response you'll see "id":"1324781965"

Answer (score 0):

if jelled is broken use https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/. You can get the user ID pretty fast